# React : check state variable has file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with file upload option. Saving the data with file is working. I have an option to edit the form. On edit, they can choose different file or can keep the existing file. On edit I'm binding the file link to a state variable   called 'sp_License'. If the user wish to change the file, after selecting then assigning file to same state variable('sp_License').
Is there any way to check if 'sp_License' has already uploaded file link or is it a new file object?

```
//on edit check
class FormFleetProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ....
            sp_License:'',
            ....
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }  
    componentDidMount() {
        getListofAllLicenses().then(results=> this.setState({
            allLicenseNumbers: results
            }))
        if(this.props.viewType=="edit"){
            this.BindEdit();
        }
        else
        this.setState({isReady: true});
    } 
    BindEdit=()=>{
        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('web_Users').doc(this.props.auth.uid);
        ref.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
            const users = doc.data();
            console.log(users)
            this.setState({
               // here i'm binding already uploaded data
                sp_License:users.sp_License,
                usr_org_StateConvered: users.usr_org_StateConvered,
               ...
                buttonName:'Update'
            },()=>{console.log(this.state)});
            } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
            }
        });
        this.setState({isReady: true});

    }

    fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.id]: e.target.files[0]
        })
     }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        .....
                //edit
                if(this.props.viewType=='edit'){
                    console.log('edit in')
                    console.log(this.state)
                    if(this.state.sp_License.includes('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/')){
                        console.log('in')
                        this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState, self.updateSuccessMessage)
                    }
                    else{
                        const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
                        const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
                        uploadTask
                            .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
                                return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                            })
                        .then(url => {
                            this.setState({ sp_License: url });
                            this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState, self.updateSuccessMessage)
                        });
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //register
                    console.log('reg in')
                    const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
                    const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);
                    uploadTask
                        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
                        return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                        })
                        .then(url => {
                        this.setState({ sp_License: url });
                        this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState, self.successMessage)
                        });
                }


            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) return null;
        console.log(this.props.viewType)
        const { classes, } = this.props;
        const { disChecked,loading,message } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                ...
                <GridContainer>

                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>

                    <input
                        accept="image/*"
                        className={classes.input}
                        id="sp_License"
                        onChange={this.fileChangeHandler}
                        multiple
                        style={{ display: 'none' }}
                        type="file"
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="sp_License">
                        <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={classes.button}>
                        <CloudUploadIcon className={classes.rightIcon} style={{marginRight:'10px'}} />  Upload License
                        </Button>
                    </label>
                    <p style={{visibility:this.props.viewType=='edit'?'visible':'hidden'}}><a href={this.state.sp_License} target="_blank">Click here to view License Copy</a></p>
                    </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>

                <GridContainer>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit} disabled={!disChecked}>
                    {loading && <CircularProgress style={{ color: 'white', height: '20px', width: '20px', marginRight: '10px' }} />}
                   {this.state.buttonName}
                  </Button>
                    </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapstateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      auth: state.firebase.auth,
      authError: state.authroot.autherr
    }
  }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, getState) => {
    return {
        UpdateUserDetails: (id, droneSPDetails,successMessage) => dispatch(UpdateUserDetails(id, droneSPDetails,successMessage))
    }
  }
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapstateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),

)(FormFleetProvider);
```

Comment: Looks like the code you added is doing what you describe. What is the actual result? In other words what doesn't work for you?

Comment: if I select any other file for upload, I'm getting the following error  'TypeError: this.state.sp_License.includes is not a function'

Comment: may be because sp_License has following value.  'sp_License: File {name: "clipart1430908.png", lastModified: 1551850437167, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 06 2019 11:03:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 55671, …}

Comment: If you don't initialise `sp_License` or initiate to `null` it would be enough to check for existence `if (this.state.sp_License)`

Comment: I have already initialized that

Comment: OK please add some more code for context (initialization and assignment part) I think i have the solution

Comment: I have added the code.. Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(users) in BindEdit ? Specifically interested in  console.log(users.sp_License)

Comment: sp_License: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dpv1-95af9.appspot.com/o/License%2Fanusha_1562929978284?alt=media&token=a08a0301-dd2a-4e77-b989-48efe18f8cfc"

Comment: Somewhere you set sp_License to be of file type, just need to find where.. Add console.log(url) everywhere **before** calling setState({sp_LIcense: url})

Comment: is there any way i can find sp_License contains file object? like this...  sp_License: File {name: "clipart1430908.png", lastModified: 1551850437167, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 06 2019 11:03:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 55671, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you `sp_License` is sometimes string and sometimes `File` object.
This is not desirable to begin with. If you want for some reason to keep this way you will need to add more checks like this

```
   if(this.state.sp_License instance of File ||
     typeof this.state.sp_License.includes  === "funthis.state.sp_License.includes('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/')){
...
}
```

Again this is not advisable it is better to keep your variables of same type during the program running time.